# postgresql dont use index on timestamptz columns

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, database-indexes, timestamp-with-timezone

Indexes on table:

```
create index shifts_start_at_idx
    on shifts (start_at);
```

Query 1 with at time zone:

```
SELECT shifts.id

FROM shifts
         JOIN stores ON shifts.store_id = stores.id AND stores.deleted_at IS NULL
         JOIN cities ON stores.city_id = cities.id
WHERE TRUE
  AND (shifts.start_at >= '2022-05-06 03:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE
                          (EXTRACT(timezone FROM cities.time_zone) * INTERVAL '1 second'))
ORDER BY shifts.start_at DESC, shifts.end_at DESC, shifts.id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Explain query 1:

```
Limit  (cost=0.86..298.93 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=0.143..25.257 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..1485256.59 rows=498300 width=24) (actual time=0.131..23.317 rows=100 loops=1)
"        Join Filter: (shifts.start_at >= timezone((date_part('timezone'::text, cities.time_zone) * '00:00:01'::interval), '2022-05-06 03:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..1209695.67 rows=1494900 width=32) (actual time=0.096..17.621 rows=100 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using shifts_admin_order_by_idx on shifts  (cost=0.43..291132.79 rows=3000000 width=32) (actual time=0.036..6.780 rows=205 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using stores_id_deleted_at_null_idx on stores  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=0 loops=205)
                    Index Cond: (id = shifts.store_id)
        ->  Index Scan using cities_pkey on cities  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=100)
              Index Cond: (id = stores.city_id)
Planning Time: 0.632 ms
Execution Time: 26.436 ms
```

Postgres doesn't use index

Query 2  without at time zone:

```
SELECT shifts.id

FROM shifts
         JOIN stores ON shifts.store_id = stores.id AND stores.deleted_at IS NULL
         JOIN cities ON stores.city_id = cities.id
WHERE TRUE
  AND (shifts.start_at >= '2022-05-06 03:00:00')
ORDER BY shifts.start_at DESC, shifts.end_at DESC, shifts.id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Explain query 2:

```
Limit  (cost=0.86..108.84 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=0.125..8.866 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..898691.17 rows=832261 width=24) (actual time=0.115..7.886 rows=100 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..761958.37 rows=832261 width=32) (actual time=0.066..5.570 rows=100 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using shifts_admin_order_by_idx on shifts  (cost=0.43..248984.02 rows=1670200 width=32) (actual time=0.014..1.380 rows=205 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (start_at >= '2022-05-06 03:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              ->  Index Scan using stores_id_deleted_at_null_idx on stores  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=205)
                    Index Cond: (id = shifts.store_id)
        ->  Index Only Scan using cities_pkey on cities  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=100)
              Index Cond: (id = stores.city_id)
              Heap Fetches: 100
Planning Time: 0.327 ms
Execution Time: 9.394 ms
```

It is not entirely clear why it does not want to use the index when converting the time to a time format with a timezone

Comment: The first query can't use an index because the index is a fixed object using a single time zone but you are looking for a time zone that you first have to extract from another column (in another table).

Comment: It is clearly using *3* indexes.  The timing difference is probably due to cache warmth.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but it seems that the right side of the expression always has the same parameter without a timezone - it is static, but not on the left side, and therefore the index is not used?